# Does Opera have config page like Firefox browser?

Tags: firefox, browser, windows-registry, opera

In Firefox browser you can type `about:config` in the address bar for a text-based list of features and options. Here you can modify values and add new entries.

Does Opera browser offer a similar feature?

**Reason behind question:**

Firefox allows you to add a feature like this:

[image: Firefox - Close Tab by Double Click]

I'm looking for a way to do this in Opera browser.

Comment: Arguably, Opera is closer to Chrome than Firefox from a settings point of view. And just an opinion, but an extension for emulating Firefox `about:config` seems a bit unlikely to exist. Perhaps it might be worthwhile to [edit] your orginal question to include the exact settings you wish to access or modify?

Comment: @Anaksunaman Done as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I found
[opera-mac-internal-pages-and-more](https://gist.github.com/christopheranderton/4945b28cde495518a62de547f33ff9b3)
that contains lots of information that you could try.

I quote some of them here:

```
opera://about/                  About Opera, Update check, Install information
opera://settings/               Manage browser settings
opera://themes/                 View and manage Opera themes and wallpapers
opera://settings/passwords/     View and manage passwords
opera://bookmarks/              View and manage bookmarks
opera://extensions/             View and manage installed extensions
opera://history/                View and manage browser history
opera://downloads/              View and manage downloaded files
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried all these, but still nothing that's similar to the Firefox `about:config` feature.  Maybe there's an extension available for Opera that does something like that?

Comment: You may make a feature request on the Opera forums.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there what exactly you search, but there many settings:
**opera://flags**
source - https://forums.opera.com/topic/47184/configure-specific-setting-about-config/4
(newer than this post, but maybe any strangers find it earlier)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1092787)